# Files and folders missing and not accessible using ls -la in ubuntu 22.04LTS

Tags: dual-boot

I am using dual O/S ubuntu 22.04 and windows 11. In one of my localdisk partition i had moved all the old files in one single folder A, and created another folder for new folder B, for my new files. I did this on while on ubuntu. I was able to see the folder till yesterday. Today, when I opened my laptop, I am no longer able to see them except the folder B. They are occupying the size on disk but are nowhere visible, neither on windows nor on ubuntu. I tried doing `ls -la` but it is giving the following output:

```
ls: cannot access 'file_name': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'file_name': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'file_name': No such file or directory
ls: cannot access 'file_name': No such file or directory
...

total 24
drwxrwxrwx  1 asif asif 20480 Nov 26  2023  .
drwxr-x---+ 3 root root  4096 Nov 25 20:40  ..
drwxrwxrwx  1 asif asif     0 Aug  4  2021 '$RECYCLE.BIN'
-?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? 'braincount umap.jpg'
d?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ?  CD
d?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? 'folder_name'
d?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? 'file_name'
-?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? 'file_name'
d?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ?  folder_name
d?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ?  folder_name
drwxrwxrwx  1 asif asif     0 Nov 16 12:12  crc_scrna
-?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? 'ppt final.pdf'
-?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? 'ppt prog.pdf'
d?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ? 'Preimplantation results'
d?????????? ? ?    ?        ?            ?  Syllabus
drwxrwxrwx  1 asif asif     0 Nov 26  2023 'System Volume Information'
drwxrwxrwx  1 asif asif     0 Nov 26  2023 'System Volume Information'
...
```

I have removed much of the repeated details from above to make it more readable.

please help me, It contains all my essential documents. I will be grateful.

I have tried `sudo chmod 755 /path/to/directory/*` and everything I could find on internet. Nothing has worked till now. please help. **#SOS**

Comment: That is a file system error.  The question now is, is the files on NTFS or on like ext4?  If NTFS you will have to run a disk check from Windows to fix it.  If it is on the ext4 you would have to reboot to Recovery Mode or to a Live USB to run a `fsck` check on the partition to fix it.

Comment: @Terrance System Volume Information implies NTFS as thats a Windows/NTFS thing. Given duplication of names, no data on files, etc. I would say this is a dead/dying disk not just a filesystem issue.  Just my two cents.

Comment: @ThomasWard You have a good eye!  I missed that part.  I could see either filesystem error or a dead / dying disk.  :)

Comment: @Terrance OP stating they dualboot also suggests an NTFS partition for interop as well, but still.  I think that they need Windows' checkdisk IF Windows ever recognizes the partition data.  If Windows doesnt recognize the drive either then the filesystem / drive is corrupt.  That's my assessment anyways :)

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your solutions. I appreciate your time.

I have rectified the error by running `checkdisk` on the partition in my windows operating system. I can see all the files and folders in both ubuntu as well as in windoes.

Thank you once again.

Best,
A.

Answer (score -1):

It seems like a permission error. You are logged in as `asif` who does not have permission to view the files in question.

To bypass this, elevate your privileges using `sudo ls -la`. In order to view the files you need to change your permissions as the user.

`sudo chmod u+rwx /*path to fileA*/`

Hope this helps!